# Watchkit popToRootController not working

Tags: swift3, watchkit

I am using a vertical page direction on my watch app, and I have a button that opens a new interface, which opens the third interface also from a button, this is done by using the modal view, and in the third interface i am calling popToRootController, because i want to go back to the first interface, but this is not working, have anyone same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dismiss` if you present view controllers **modally** using `presentControllerWithName`.

You can use `popToRootController` or `popController` if you present the view controllers **hierarchically** using `pushControllerWithName`.

You can read more on the Apple [Interface Navigation guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html).

In your example if you want to dismiss twice, you will have to pass a delegate or closure with the context to your second controller. Then you can call the delegate method or closure after `dismiss()` on the third controller. The implementation of the delegate method or closure will be another `dismiss()`.